# Memory warnings with UIImagePickerController in iOS 5 but not in ios 4.x

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

This seems to be a problem with `UIImagePickerController` in iOS 5 .

I have an app developed xcode4.3 I tested it on two iPhones (iOS 4.3 and 5.1)

```
{

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.view.tag = tag;
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            if ( imagePicker.view.tag == 1) 
            { //Editing doent allowed for biz card
                  imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
                  [Flurry logEvent:@"Edit Contacts:Attempt to add an image for the Contact picture using the camera"];
            }
            else {
                  [Flurry logEvent:@"Edit Contacts:Attempt to add an image for the Business Card picture using the camera"];
            }
            [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
            [imagePicker release];

}
```

If the device is iOS 4.1

No leaks / no memory warning when a photo is either taken or selected from the library (tested on a device running iOS 4.1).

The same code tested on a device running iOS 5.1 I have faced memory warnings level 1 regularly when the photo is taken from camera capture.

y..? & how to resolve this issue..?

Comment: Share some code related to take picture...

Answer (score 2):

Try this & check:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Add this method & check.

also add like that & check:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.view.tag = tag;
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            if ( imagePicker.view.tag == 1) 
            { //Editing doent allowed for biz card
                  imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
                  [Flurry logEvent:@"Edit Contacts:Attempt to add an image for the Contact picture using the camera"];
            }
            else {
                  [Flurry logEvent:@"Edit Contacts:Attempt to add an image for the Business Card picture using the camera"];
            }
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: alrdy i used it to dismiss picker

Comment: This line: [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil]